# Gradient when changing coordinate system

Tags: multivariable-calculus, coordinate-systems

A change of variables from $\vec{r_1}$, $\vec{r_2}$ to $\vec{r}$, $\vec{R}$ is given by:

$$
\vec{r} = \vec{r_1}-\vec{r_2}\text{ , }\vec{R}=c_1 \vec{r_1} + c_2 \vec{r_2}
$$

I'm supposed to find $\nabla_1$ expressed in terms of $\nabla_r$ and $\nabla_R$. The suggested solution starts out with

$$
\vec{R}=(X, Y, Z)\text{ , } \vec{r} = (x, y, z)
$$

and then goes on to state that

$$
(\nabla_1)_x = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} = \frac{\partial X}{\partial x_1} \frac{\partial}{\partial X} + \frac{\partial x}{\partial x_1} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \text{ , }
$$

where does (the second equality of) this last expression come from?

Comment: It's the multivariate chain rule.

Comment: Shouldn't that be $(\nabla_1)_{x_1}$? ... assuming eg. $\vec{r_1}=(x_1,y_1,z_1)$